# jquery mobile form input text on Android

Tags: android, jquery, mobile, cordova

I'm making an App with Cordova-Phongap 1.9.0 on Android, using Jquery Mobile. I'm trying to make an input text forms like the followings example

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<label for="name">Text Input:</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" value=""  />
</div>
```

When i try it on the device or virtual device, the focus is on the input type, i see the virtual keyboard, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you upload your sample somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a very similar problems with form inputs using Android and Phonegap 1.9.0.
In my case it was due to using a menu at the top of the page.

```
position:fixed;
z-index: 1;
```

Once I had removed this CSS the forms worked again (although my menu is no longer fixed as I wanted it to be...)

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was going to the stock index.css file and changing

```
-webkit-user-select: none;                  /* prevent copy paste, to allow, change 'none' to 'text' */
```

to

```
-webkit-user-select: text;                  /* prevent copy paste, to allow, change 'none' to 'text' */
```